# Windows millisecond timing - without busywait?

Tags: .net, c, windows, timing

I am writing an application translating input from one device to another - say one format of head tracking to another, mostly used to provide support for multiple types of head tracking in games.

Most often, the input to my program is delivered by polling shared memory. However, doing so in a tight loop needlessly consumes a CPU core. It is imperative that the application doesn't degrade the gaming experience.

The default schedule time on Windows seems to be 60 hz, so sleep is pretty much out. I need less than 5 ms, but the occasional blip is okay.

I'd rather not affect the system configuration by affecting the system wide timer.

What are my options to prevent consuming a core, but still mostly execute some method once every 1-5 milliseconds or so, using C or .net?

I am looking for solutions for windows 7.

Comment: Interrupts didn't help you...?? Just a little bit curious about it...

Comment: @HirenPandya help me how? I have no device generating interrupts for me, since they (input devices) use shared memory?

Comment: `the input to my program is delivered by polling shared memory` about this line, I am bit confused, I mean, Can't your program be interrupted whenever the input is available in the shared memory from any input device. I am still confused a bit in your question, so placing some silly but clearing points..

Comment: @HirenPandya no problem, and thanks :) the program could be interrupted, but the protocols used most often does not contain synchronization except locking the shared memory..   It is not something I can rely on, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the OS version you're interested in XP or Vista+?

Comment: Will 'normal' inter-process synchro not work well enough - named events/semaphores?  Why do you have to poll?  Polling for input is hopeless.

Comment: @MartinJames I would gladly do so, but the input devices are proprietary, and the library to access most of them don't include events. Just named mutexes to lock the shared memory. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Max not really.  You probably realise that the proprietary design is probably 'less-than-optimal' :(

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your only two options are:

1. Using [Multimedia Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but you seem to dislike the idea.
2. Sprinkling a function call in all of your long loops, checking there the `TSC` or the [`Performance Counter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and executing whatever needs to be executed if the time is right.

Comment: I used multimedia timers on a project about 10 years ago with 1ms timeouts without affecting system wide timers.

Comment: @Neil As far as I understand it, if there is another user of multimedia timers, there can be some interference between the two.

Comment: Thanks. I will reevaluate mm timers, but my last try, and msdn documentation if I recall correctly, said that they require the use of beginsettime to achieve ms timers. Do you know how win32 forms or wpf achieves low latency, without consuming a whole cpu?

Comment: From what I remember, as long as you set a divisible interval, there shouldn't be a problem.  IE  3ms will cause problems if there are 5ms timers already, but if you choose 1ms, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I don't know about forms and WPF, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

If interprocess synchronization is out of the question, try to use `SetTimer` function. It can invoke your callback with millisecond interval.

If you want a millisecond-grained sleep, you can use `WaitForSingleObject`. Just give it some event handle that never changes own state.

However all these options are quite unreliable, as Windows doesn't give you guarantee of timing, and if the system get overloaded, the results will be not very good.

Comment: -1. You [can't get better than 10 ms out of `SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The OP needs 1 to 5 ms.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I believe that depends on OS used. For example, Windows 8 RT might be able to get the desired result. But generally I agree: on Windows, it is very difficult (almost impossible) to guarantee required response time.